# Is there a way to identify specific nodes on websites like airbnb?

Tags: r

I am currently learning how to use R to create a scraper. I have been able to scrape some texts that are relevant, but when trying to scrape the room rate from an airbnb listing, I'm having no luck. Is there a way to identify the node to do so?

I am currently highlighting the room rate on the airbnb listing, and viewing its source. When doing so with the title and location of the listing, I am succeeding, but when using the source to try and get the room rate, I have no luck.

```
<span class="_doc79r">$57</span>
##above is what I believe where it is located

##below is the code I'm using to try and get the room rate
airbnb_wvpg %>%
  html_node("._doc79r") %>%
  html_text()
```

I expect the output to give me the room rate, which is $57 in my case, but the actual output is: [1] NA

Comment: Please add a complete example including libraries you're loading.

Comment: I am currently using rvest, lubridade, stringr, and LSAfun.

I am using these based on a video I saw.